# Laravel "Next ErrorException: A non well formed numeric value encountered" php-7.4

Tags: php, laravel, http-status-code-500

Когда я пытаюсь открыть сайт, появляется ошибка HTTP 500, а лог Laravel показывает: "A non well formed numeric value encountered"

Вот значение `$sec` перед выполнениям `intval(($sec / 60) % 60)`. Значение `60,316000` и тип этого значения: `string`.

Вот содержимое файла index.blade.php: https://pastebin.com/Cv8hsndU

Вот содержимое файла helpers.php: https://pastebin.com/1TSY2rTC

Есть идея, как я могу это исправить, в файле `index.blade.php`, где вызывается эта функция (строки 29,50,86,122,150), код, который вызывает ее, выглядит следующим образом:

```
        @if($recomment != NULL)
            @foreach($recomment as $result)
                <?php $video_categories = get_video_form_cat($result->ID) ?>
                @if(count($video_categories)>0)
                    <h2>Recommended Category For You <a style="text-decoration: none" href="{{URL('categories/')}}/{{$result->ID}}.{{$result->post_name}}.html"><span>-{{$result->title_name}}</span></a></h2>
                    <div class="row content-image">
                         @foreach($video_categories as $result)
                            <?php $rating=GetRatingVideo($result->string_Id);?>
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3  image-left">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="col_img">
                                        <span class="hd">HD</span>
                                        <a href="{{URL('watch')}}/{{$result->string_Id.'/'.$result->post_name}}.html">
                                            <img src="{{$result->getImageUrl($result->poster)}}" alt="{{$result->title_name}}" height="177" />
                                        </a>
                                        <div class="position_text">
                                            <p class="icon-like"></p>
                                            <p class="percent">{{floor($rating['percent_like'])}}%</p>
                                            <p class="time_minimute">{{sec2hms($result->duration)}}</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <h3><a href="{{URL('watch')}}/{{$result->string_Id.'/'.$result->post_name}}.html">{{str_limit($result->title_name,30)}}</a></h3>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        @endforeach
                    </div>
                @endif
            @endforeach
        @endif
```

Вот функция, вызывающая эту ошибку (helpers.php):

```
   function sec2hms ($sec, $padHours = false)
         {
            $hms = "";
            $hours = intval(intval($sec) / 3600);
            if($hours > 0){
              $hms .= ($padHours)? str_pad($hours, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT). ':': $hours. ':';  
            }
            $minutes = intval(($sec / 60) % 60);
            $hms .= str_pad($minutes, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT). ':';
            $seconds = intval($sec % 60);
            $hms .= str_pad($seconds, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
            return $hms;
        }
```

Вот полное сообщение об ошибке из лога Laravel:

```
Next ErrorException: A non well formed numeric value encountered (View: /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/resources/views/home/index.blade.php) in /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/app/Helper/helpers.php:35
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/PhpEngine.php(44): Illuminate\View\Engines\CompilerEngine->handleViewException()
#1 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/CompilerEngine.php(58): Illuminate\View\Engines\PhpEngine->evaluatePath()
#2 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(135): Illuminate\View\Engines\CompilerEngine->get()
#3 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(106): Illuminate\View\View->getContents()
#4 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(80): Illuminate\View\View->renderContents()
#5 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Response.php(51): Illuminate\View\View->render()
#6 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Response.php(198): Illuminate\Http\Response->setContent()
#7 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(1229): Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response->__construct()
#8 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(112): Illuminate\Routing\Router->prepareResponse()
#9 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}()
#10 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(139): call_user_func()
#11 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#12 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(102): call_user_func()
#13 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(114): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then()
#14 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(68): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack()
#15 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(203): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch()
#16 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(134): Illuminate\Routing\Route->runWithCustomDispatcher()
#17 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(708): Illuminate\Routing\Route->run()
#18 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}()
#19 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(139): call_user_func()
#20 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#21 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(102): call_user_func()
#22 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(710): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then()
#23 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(674): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRouteWithinStack()
#24 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(635): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute()
#25 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(236): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch()
#26 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}()
#27 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(139): call_user_func()
#28 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php(50): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#29 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php(31): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken->handle()
#30 [internal function]: App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken->handle()
#31 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array()
#32 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#33 [internal function]: Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle()
#34 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array()
#35 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(62): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#36 [internal function]: Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession->handle()
#37 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array()
#38 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#39 [internal function]: Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle()
#40 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array()
#41 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php(59): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#42 [internal function]: Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies->handle()
#43 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array()
#44 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(44): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#45 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle()
#46 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array()
#47 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#48 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(102): call_user_func()
#49 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(122): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then()
#50 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(87): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter()
#51 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/index.php(96): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle()
#52 {main}
```

Comment: Перевести ошибку и вникнуть в то, что на обозначает самостоятельно не пробовали?

Comment: @DanielProtopopov пробовал, не помогло.